# How to use the word "wagered"

Tags: word-usage, past-participles

In a game of slot machines, can you call a payline you bet on "a wagered payline"? I am not sure if it is the payline that is wagered, or my money are wagered on (upon?) this payline.

Comment: You wager your money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary entries for *[wager](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wager#Noun)* as a noun or verb include:

> (noun) That on which bets are laid; the subject of a bet
>   (verb) To bet something; to put it up as collateral

Usage of “[wagered on](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wagered%20on%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en)” and “[wagered upon](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wagered%20upon%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en)” can be seen in links obtained via [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wagered+on%2Cwagered+upon&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) for *wagered on,wagered upon*.  *Wagered on* is used substantially more often than is *wagered upon*.  Examples include

> • The gross commission shall be first deducted from the gross amount wagered on each individual pool...
>   • If the book is balanced in terms of amounts wagered on each side of the proposition, what is the outcome for the sports book?
>   • The money wagered on these three horses totals $2,000 and is distributed as follows: ...
>   • “I never wagered upon your honor, Llewelyn. I wagered upon your common sense."
>   • The new Madison Avenue guard, in contrast, wagered upon the attractiveness of the messages of U.S. popular culture ...

Returning to your question, if you place a bet on a payline, it is reasonable to say you have wagered upon it.  Calling that payline a *wagered payline* is possible, but perhaps a stretch.  Calling it a *covered payline* might be better.